# Calculate element width before resize against width after resize

Tags: jquery

To set the margin of an element I'd like to calculate it's difference in size before browser resize and after.  How would I access the resizeW variable outside of the resize function, or use the startW inside the resize function without it changing.

---

```
var startW = $('li').width(); // width before resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    var resizeW = $('li').width(); // width after resize
    var diff = (startW - resizeW); // startW and resizeW are the same
} );
$('li').css('margin-left',(startW - resizeW)); // resizeW is not defined
```

For example: If the element I'm getting the width of is 300 pixels before resize and then I trigger resize. Afterwards the element is 200 pixels. I want to calculate the difference. 300 - 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $li = $('li'),         // Cache your element
    startW = $li.width();  // Store a variable reference

function setMarginDiff(){  // Create a function that modifies the margin
    var currW = $li.width(),
        diff = startW - currW ; 
    $li.css({marginLeft : diff}); 
}

setMarginDiff();                 // Do on DOM ready
$(window).resize(setMarginDiff); // and on resize
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  StartW and currW are always the same.

Comment: @dcc how is that possible? http://jsbin.com/kokud/1/edit?js,console,output // What are you trying to do actually here?

Comment: @dcc your'e trying to keep the element at the same left-position even if we resize the window? I think your asking an *XY Question*. You should rather explain what are your trying to do and why, cause your question is too specific and might not resolve your task in the best possible way, while to accomplish the general idea there might be better solutions than the one you're doing right now.

Comment: If the element I'm getting the width of is 300 pixels before resize and then I trigger resize.  Aftewards the element is 200 pixels.  I want to calculate the difference.  300 - 200

Comment: @dcc ok that's exactly what you can see perform in the demo link I posted in my comment above. What part of that demo does **not** work for you?

Comment: Didn't have a chance to check out the link last night.  Gonna check it out right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your resizeW is defined in the inside of the function... so you have a scope problem... try the following:

```
var startW = $('li').width(); // width before resize
var resizeW = startW;
$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeW = $('li').width(); // width after resize
    var diff = (startW - resizeW); // startW and resizeW are the same
} );
$('li').css('margin-left',(startW - resizeW)); // resizeW is not defined
```

Comment: On initial load this will not work as `(startW - resizeW)` will produce `NaN`. To get around this you can do `var startW = resizeW = $(li).width()`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that the resize will be called when the window is resized, but you are doing the `$('li').css('margin-left',(startW - resizeW));` just after declaring the resize listener, so it will do nothing even if you put the `var resizeW` outside.

I think `startW` should not be the same as `resizeW`inside the resize function, so there has to be something more. If you want to change the margin-left every time the window is resized, just put the `$('li').css('margin-left',(diff));` also inside the resize function.